# udev doesn't want to run chgrp and chmod

Tags: linux, udev

I want to change brightness of my monitor via the `/sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness` file. But the file has `-rw-r--r--.` permissions, so only root can write to it. [This article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#ACPI) says, that I can configure a udev rule for changing the permissions. It doesn't work. I have little bit modified the rule, to match my computer. My graphiphics card is `radeon_b10`, not `acpi_video0` .

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="radeon_b10", RUN+="/usr/bin/chgrp video /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="radeon_b10", RUN+="/usr/bin/chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness"
```

I have tried everything. Monitoring the rules using `$ udevadm monitor` and triggering the rules using `# udevadm trigger --action=add /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0`. The rules are fired, but the file `/sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness` is still:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Aug  1 16:09 brightness
```

(output from `$ ll -a /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/`)

Why udev doesn't execute the `RUN` statement?

Info about my system:

```
[marian@bagr ~]$ uname -a
Linux bagr 4.17.9-200.fc28.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 23 21:41:29 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[marian@bagr ~]$ ll -a /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    0 Aug  1  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root    0 Aug  1  2018 ..
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Aug  1 16:09 actual_brightness
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Aug  1 16:09 bl_power
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Aug  1 16:09 brightness
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Aug  1 16:09 device -> ../../card0-eDP-1
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Aug  1 16:09 max_brightness
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    0 Aug  1 16:09 power
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Aug  1  2018 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/backlight
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Aug  1 16:09 type
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Aug  1 16:09 uevent
[marian@bagr ~]$ udevadm info -q all -a /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/radeon_bl0':
    KERNEL=="radeon_bl0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="backlight"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{actual_brightness}=="30"
    ATTR{bl_power}=="0"
    ATTR{brightness}=="30"
    ATTR{max_brightness}=="255"
    ATTR{type}=="raw"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1':
    KERNELS=="card0-eDP-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="drm"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{dpms}=="On"
    ATTRS{edid}==""
    ATTRS{enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{status}=="connected"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0':
    KERNELS=="card0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="drm"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:01.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="radeon"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{boot_vga}=="1"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x030000"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="40"
    ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="Unknown speed"
    ATTRS{current_link_width}=="0"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x9850"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="40"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="35"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="Unknown speed"
    ATTRS{max_link_width}=="255"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power_dpm_force_performance_level}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power_dpm_state}=="balanced"
    ATTRS{power_method}=="dpm"
    ATTRS{power_profile}=="default"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x40"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x81f5"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x103c"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1002"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: sysfs doesn't actually support changing permissions.

Comment: oh, really? sad.. Is there any way how to get this working? Why udev rules have `GROUP`, `OWNER` and `MODE`? What about creating a symlink?

Comment: Because udev affects things under `/dev`, which is essentially always on a filesystem that supports changing permissions.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the file to be changed does not yet exist.

Run a script instead of chown and chmod that can examine whether the target exists and can write information to a log file.

Comment: Now I have `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="basklight", KERNEL=="radeon_b10", RUN+="/home/marian/bin/udevcheck.sh"` in my rule. The script is `tree -l -L 2 /sys/class/backlight/ > /home/marian/bin/udevcheck.log`. It is marked a executable and has a shebang. The file `udevcheck.log` doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh, I had a typo in my test rule, but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `change` action instead of the `add` and everything works:

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="radeon_b10", RUN+="/usr/bin/chgrp video /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness"
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="radeon_b10", RUN+="/usr/bin/chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness"
```