# Group ownership changes by itself on restart

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, group, sysfs, ownership

I changed window managers and now need to be able to change `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` (because the new wm cannot change screen brightness natively).

I created a user group called `brightness`, added myself to the group, and ran `sudo chown root:brightness /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`.

Now, every time I restart my computer the group ownership of the file changes to `video` instead of `brightness`. Previously, this file was owned by `root:root` and remained that way.

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root video 4096 Sep  4 11:10 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
$ sudo chown root:brightness /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
$ ls -l /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root brightness 4096 Sep  4 11:10 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

So now I have to `chown` that file every time I restart my computer. What is happening?

(I am running Ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: Have you tried to add yourself to `video` instead?

Comment: @xenoid, I could do that, but I'm curious to know why the ownership is changing in the first place.

Comment: @Umang because the `/sys` filesystem is ephemeral - you can try using `udev` instead as discussed here: [udev doesn't want to run chgrp and chmod](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459874/udev-doesnt-want-to-run-chgrp-and-chmod)

Comment: @steeldriver, Thank you! I read up about `/sys` and the link you pointed to. I got `udev` to change the permissions. It works perfectly. If you want to post an answer, I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: @Umang how to do that with `udev`?